# Copying Files to usb or external drive

Tags: read-only, copy

Am not able to copy files to usb or external hdd, it shows an error saying destination is read only, while in previous version  i was succesfuly doing the same.Also i can easily paste files in windows os.

Comment: This link might help you, [In Linux the mode of NTFS (and FAT32) is determined by the partition's mount options. You cannot change it via chmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

Answer (score 0):

The destination drives are mounted, but for whatever reason, they've been mounted read-only. If you right-click on the mounted drive in nautilus (started as gksudo, like you did before), a dropdown menu appears. Go to Properties at the bottom, and then to the "Permissions" tab. Maybe it will let you change the permissions to "write" there and the problem will go away.